# Add word to the end of a each line in all files using regex notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have 10 files of 100 lines each. I need to do their translation.

This is one line in some file: `"Client Notes,141"`

and another simular word line in another file `"Client Notes,700"`

I want to modify all the concerned lines in all the 10 files to be:

```
"Client Notes,141,KundLinjer"
"Client Notes,700,KundLinjer"
"Client Notes,770,KundLinjer"
```

I tried with regular expressions and macros but I couldn figure it out

Thanks for help!

Comment: Please make your title and tags coherent, is it Notepad2 or Notepad++?

Comment: Thanks for updating. Does [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52261970/372239) work for you?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming it is Notepad++ and not Notepad2:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `\bClient Notes,\h*\d+\K`
- Replace with: `,KundLinjer`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
\b              : word boundary
Client Notes,   : literally
\h*             : 0 or more horizontal spaces
\d+             : 1 or more digits
\K              : forget all we have seen until this position
```

**Result for given example:**

```
Client Notes,141,KundLinjer
Client Notes,700,KundLinjer
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try the following find and replace:

**Find:**

```
^Client Notes,(\\d+)
```

**Replace:**

```
Client Notes,$1,KundLinjer
```

To make it apply to multiple files, use the directory option in the dialog to select the folder which contains the 10 files.  If the 10 files be scattered in multiple places, then create a single folder containing those files.  Also, make sure you do the find and replace with regex mode enabled.

Answer (score 0):

In nodepad++ you can use the shortcut: `Ctrl+H` and under the `Replace` tab, `search mode` select `Regular expression`

**Find:**
`(Client Notes, \d+)`

**Replace:**
`\1, KundLinjer`

You have the option to:
`Replace All in All Opened Documents`.

**Explanation**

The brackets (client Notes, \d+) will 'capture' anything within the brackets to be used in our replacement `\1` (if you had more captures, you could use `\2`, `\3` etc..)

\d+ means any digit, one or more times (in your case 141, 700).

So we are replacing the text "Client Notes (AnyNumber)" with "Client Notes (AnyNumber) KundLinjer".

You could also replace `(.*)` with `\1 KundLinjer` if you want to add `KundLinjer` to all lines, no matter what.

Comment: Please provide some additional information regarding your answer's possible solution.

Comment: @StanislavMekhonoshin updated my answer with more info